# How to not insert a Tab each time I press Enter in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, editor

I'm currently programming in Scala using the IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 IDE. When I'm declaring a method, I usually do it like this:

```
def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
{
  val result: Int = a + b
  result
}
```

After the equal sign, I press "Enter" -> "{" -> "Enter". That gives the codestyle from above.

But for some reason, in IntelliJ each time I press "Enter" after the equal sing, the editor automatically inserts a "Tab", giving the codestyle from bellow:

```
def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
  {
    val result: Int = a + b
    result
  }
```

It's as if the editor thinks I'm programming in Python or something like that, or as if I were typing "Enter" -> *"Tab"* -> "{" -> "Enter".

I tried search that option in the codestyle but I did not found anything related to that.

Is there any way this can be resolved or made editable? I get quite a bit annoyed by that, so it would be very helpful if you could assist me with this.

For everything else, I hope you guys are having a nice week, best regards!

Comment: You have to adjust your code style and autoformatting settings in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as per Scala code conventions, you should write

```scala
def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  val result: Int = a + b
  result
}
```

Or even better (as your function body can be written as an expression instead of a blcok)

```scala
def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

Or,

```scala
def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = 
  a + b
```

And should not do this,

```scala
def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
{
  val result: Int = a + b
  result
}
```

IntelliJ has automatic code styling capabilities and it contains some simple conventions for many languages.

So, in this particular case. You should fix your code style.

But, if you really really want to disable this pretty useful auto indent thing, then you can completely disable it by setting everything (tab size, indent and continuation indent) to 0 in `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Scala > Tabs and Indents`.

But, if you are doing this then you will probably want to disable all other Code Style features as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the thing is I didn't found in the codesytle the option to dismiss the Tab each time I press the enter :( but I think its my bad to not specify that in the question. Anyway, thanks for all!

Comment: @GabrielSantanaParedes Again, I would not suggest doing this. But I have added the way to disable auto indentation.

Comment: @sarvesheri Hey! I just found it with your help! Thank you so much. Also yeah, I'm planing to take you recommendations; I'm going to start styling the code as you suggest but I also wanted to know how to remove that for just common knowledge. Have a nice one 